# ESLint shared configuration for all rules within a plugin

Tags: javascript, eslint

I've created a es lint plugin that provides me with a rule which checks that provided import is not in a dynamic list of blacklisted imports.

The list is loaded from a JSON file.

Currently I am loading this file in the `create` method of a rule, but the rule is being recreated for each file, which in turn makes the linter slow.

I've found the following text in the ESLint documentation, but no other mention of a way to share some global object within an invocation of the linter.

> https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#adding-shared-settings
>
> ESLint supports adding shared settings into configuration files.
> **Plugins use settings to specify information that should be shared across all of its rules.** You can add settings object to ESLint
> configuration file and it will be supplied to every rule being
> executed. This may be useful if you are adding custom rules and want
> them to have access to the same information and be easily
> configurable.

Is this supported? I've tried exporting a settings object in the index.js of the plugin, but it is not being picked up at all.

```
module.exports.settings = {
    "sharedData": "Hello"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I already have a workaround, but wondering if someone will come up with a better solution.

What I did in the end was to load the configuration in the index of the rule itself, which is loaded at the start of ESLint.

Instead of depending on `context.getCwd()` I've fallen back to _dirname. Which proved to be enough for my use case.